# Clear Text Field in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, reset

Is there any pluin for Jquery mobile that allows to clear the text box?? I want [something like this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/jquery/clearable-textboxes/)

When I implement the above demo, cross button comes out of the text box in Jquery Mobile.

Can someomne help me out. Thanks for your time.

my code as of now

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <title></title> 

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.clearable.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.clearable.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />


</head> 

<body> 

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Textbox Clear Demo</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div id="content">
    <input type="text" id="clearMe"></input>

    <input type="text" id="clearYou"></input>
    </div>


    <div data-role="footer">
        <small>&#169; 2011 EyePax IT Consulting</small>
    </div><!-- /footer -->



</div><!-- /page -->
<SCRIPT>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clearMe').clearable()
});
</SCRIPT>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you write your code? Give us a piece of the code with the clear statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tutorial for your demo with all the code you need:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2011/02/clearable-textbox-jquery.html

Just include the [js file](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/jquery/clearable-textboxes/jquery.clearable.js), add the class to all inputs:

```
<input type="text" id="clearMe" class="clearable" />
```

and run it:

```
<SCRIPT>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.clearable').clearable()
});
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 14):

Old question, but someone asked me about this today.

As of JQuery Mobile 1.3.0 you can just add:

```
data-clear-btn="true"
```

to your input control (except textarea) and a clear button will be rendered.

See new docs:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/forms/textinputs/#

Hope it helps any new searchers!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered `$("#textboxid").val('');` ?

Edit: answer to 1'st comment

As you can see in your example the field in which you try to paste actually is a DIV container that contains 2 elements: the input text field and a image with a link that triggers the clear event.

Code here:

```
<div id="sq" class="clearable style1 divclearable">
<input type="text" class="clearable style1" size="30">
<a class="clearlink" href="javascript:" title="Click to clear this textbox"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: cross box inside textbox I need.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I created, check it out on [github](https://github.com/mahpour/bootstrap-input-clear-button) there're samples on the page you can use.

Answer (score 0):

here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3nigma/M2deX/6/) because you have not posted the code its the best i can come up with

**UPDATE**

here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3nigma/QfMhn/3/) according to your code, note that i have removed the `</input>` tags as its not valid HTML.